# not working mysql_fetch_array and also not showing its error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**getting could not connect**
*Following given was my problem raising query section.i am under pressure totally confused.if anybody known solution please here update me .thanks*
above included dp connection file also
my **catcode** variable like as **SCA1005,SCB1001...**

case childprdadd:
    $data = explode('~',$_GET['data']);

```
//hint:->value = categorie+'~'+childprd+'~'+childqty+'~'+childcolor+'~'+catcode

$category_name = $data[0];
$childprod_name = $data[1];
$child_qty = $data[2];
$child_color = $data[3];
$cat_code = $data[4];
//echo $category_name.'+'.$childprod_name.'+'.$child_qty.'+'.$child_color.'+'.$cat_code;
$split = str_split($cat_code);
$pos = $split[2];

switch($pos)
{
    case 'A':
$child1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child1_subcategory where code = '".$cat_code."'"))or die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
$des1 = $child1['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$child1['cat_id']."',sub_cat_id = '".$child1['id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$des1."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");

break;

case 'B':
$child2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child2_subcategory where code = '".$cat_code."'"));
$des2 = $child1['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$child2['cat_id']."',sub_cat_id = '".$child2['sub_cat_id']."',child1_id = '".$child2['child1_id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$des2."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");
break;

case 'C':
$child3 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child3_subcategory where code = '".$cat_code."'"));
$des3 = $child3['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$child3['cat_id']."',sub_cat_id = '".$child3['sub_cat_id']."',child1_id = '".$child3['child1_id']."',child2_id = '".$child3['child2_id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$des3."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");
break;

case 'D':
$child4 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child4_subcategory where code = '".$cat_code."'"));
$des4 = $child4['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$child4['cat_id']."',sub_cat_id = '".$child4['sub_cat_id']."',child1_id = '".$child4['child1_id']."',child2_id = '".$child4['child2_id']."',child3_id = '".$child4['child3_id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$des4."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");
break;

case 'E':
$child5 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child5_subcategory where code = '".$cat_code."'"));
$des5 = $child5['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$child5['cat_id']."',sub_cat_id = '".$child5['sub_cat_id']."',child1_id = '".$child5['child1_id']."',child2_id = '".$child5['child2_id']."',child3_id = '".$child5['child3_id']."',child4_id = '".$child5['child4_id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$des5."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");
break;

case 'T':
$cat = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from goldsun_child_category where code = '".$cat_code."'"));
$cat_des = $cat['description'].'->'.$childprd_name;

mysql_query("insert into goldsun_child_product set cat_id = '".$cat_des['cat_id']."',name = '".$childprd_name."',qty = '".$childprd_qty."', description = '".$cat_des."',color_id = '".$child_color."',category_name = '".$category_name."',code = '".$cat_code."'");
break;

}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new MySQL or the old MySQL? If you're using the old MySQL ([which has been deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)), check your "INSERT" command. If you're using the new MySQL (with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)), try to learn it and use [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

If you're using the old version of MySQL, maybe you need:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect(server,username,password);
$bla = mysql_query($con,"INSERT into goldsun_child_product (cat_id, sub_cat_id, name, qty, blablabla) VALUES (".$child1['cat_id'].",".$child1['id'].",".$blablabla."");
$child = mysql_fetch_array($bla);
?>
```

If you're using the new version, try to learn MySQLi or PDO with prepared statement.

Comment: i am using following version,   Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
    MySQL client version: 5.1.37
    PHP extension: mysqli
insert command and db connection is not problem.another my queries also working well.but here not fetching the table data's.can you know help me out this problems.thanks for your response

Comment: instead of passing mysql_query in mysql_fetch_array, please use separately like mysql_query then mysql_fetch_array

Comment: you said way to separated mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array.but not working.what i do? not showing error.am very confused.here before i was using same way only but without bootstrap skin but its working.only after integrated with bootstrap skin not working above fetch area!!!..thanks